# has_many :polymorphic through has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

How to embody the following idea in Rails 4:

```
class Package < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :products through :categories
  has_many :insurances, through :categories
end

  class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :categories
  has_many :products through :categories
  has_many :insurances, through :categories
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :packages
  has_many :products, as: :productable
  has_many :insurances, as: :productable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to productable, polymorphic: true
end
```

products can belong not only to the package, but also to the template.

The question is how to make so that product upon save automatically set correct productable_type and insurancable_id?

For example

```
package.categories.first.products.create(name: 'asdasd')
```

should have a `productable_type = 'Package'` and `productable_id: package.id` whilst

```
template.categories.first.products.create(name: 'asdasd')
```

should have `productable_type = 'Template'` and `productable_id: template.id`

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is. You've written rails code, and are asking what about rails 4?

Comment: it's not an actual code, just an illustration of the idea

Comment: @DavidAldridge I updted the question

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you are looking for is http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AutosaveAssociation.html

This will persist the associated records first allowing the type and id to be present.